# R or python code (or other means) to mass convert ESRI's E00 files into shapefiles

Tags: python, r, arcgis, shapefile

Since ArcGIS pro and ArcMap no longer support functions to mass convert E00 files, I am looking for a means to mass convert ESRI's E00 files into shapefiles. Specifically, I hope to use this to mass convert the Canadian Ice Service's ice charts (pre-2020) from E00 to shapefiles.

Does anyone have an R or python code (or other means) to mass convert ESRI's E00 files into shapefiles?

I know you can convert E00 in ArcMap and ArcPro but was hoping for a way to mass convert files.

Thank you!

Comment: You might have more luck with this question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Solver here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222548/loading-esri-arcgrid-export-file-e00-in-r if the problem is how to iterate the files in a folder to read and write to ESRI Shapefile let us know

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can work using R.

```
library(rgdal)

## Folder containing e00 files
folder <- "C:/data/my_files/"

## Read and convert e00 into shp

e00_files <- list.files(folder, pattern=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
e00_names <- list.files(folder, pattern=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)

for(i in 1:length(e00_files)){
  f <- readOGR(e00_files[[i]])
  n <- gsub(".e00", ".shp", e00_names[[i]])
  writeOGR(f, dsn=paste0(folder, n), layer=n, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
}
```